# What is this thorny plant with cute leaves?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found this thorny plant with cute leaves growing in my garden in India,

I took a risk by plucking it to get photos of the front & back side of the leaves.

Front side of the leaf:

[image]

Back side of leaf:

[image]

Full plant:

[image]

Any Idea what this plant is?

Comment: Full Plant: http://i.imgur.com/0IlEj2G.jpg

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalbergia_melanoxylon

The Mpingo looks quite similar to this plant. However, more information is needed like the approximate size of the leaves and the number of leaves on a branch.

Comment: No, That is a wrong answer.